# Generating Keystroke With the Kinect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm currently working on a project for the final year of my degree and am having some trouble with the coding aspect, being fairly new to C# and unity. I'm using the Kinect, unity and zigfu package and i want to use the persons position in relation to the kinect to generate keystroke. Eg if the player is closer to the kinect it will trigger the forward button to be pressed, if they are farther away then it will trigger the back back button with a neutral area in the middle.

```
//has user moved back
if (rootPosition.z < -2)
{
//print(rootPosition.z);
v = -1;
}

//has user moved forward
if (rootPosition.z > -1)
{
//print(rootPosition.z);
v = 1;
}
```

I've managed to find the section which registers where i am in relation to the kinect but don't know how to trigger keystroke. Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated as the deadline is fast approaching and i'm struggling with the technical side of things.

Comment: Slightly confused w/ your question.  Are you trying to generate a global Window's keystroke event or are you trying to do something in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this in the past for Simulated Keystrokes:

[Windows Input Simulator (C# SendInput Wrapper - Simulate Keyboard and Mouse)](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)